# Two events with configured PRICE - Price option is only showing on one

Tags: civievent, registration, price-sets

I have 2 similar Civi events setup on a drupal site.

Price tab is not using existing Price sets (for both) but customly added price options. Screenshots (in dutch, sorry) attached.

FIRST EVENT
[image]

SECOND EVENT
[image]

So for one event, the price options are printed on the registration form.
For the other, the price isn't printed.

I checked into /sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/**CRM/Price/Form/PriceSet.tpl**

And for the second event, **$priceSet is empty.** This is why the price isn't printed.

I'm still clueless though as to why this could be.

Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: Hi. I might drop 'price set' out of the Tags for this question as this seems clearly to be a question about the non-price-set approach. Are there any other differences to the Events. Are both public, enabled, can you provide then end part of the path to both events. just trying to think what other clues you can provide. you have explained the issue well but nothing leaps out.

Comment: Do you have any customisations relating to Events?

Comment: Hey. Both are not public, both are active. There are no other differences between both events. I have even tried making absolutely everything the same: event type, max participants, etc. No luck whatsoever.

The <div id="priceset" class="crm-section price_set-section"> just isn't printed entirely, because the $priceSet is empty in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The option "approval required" breaks the price option.

When that option is checked, the price options are not printed on the registration page. No idea why this behaviour is standard though.

My client needs to check this option AND needs to ask about price option, so in the current civi-logic (this is becoming a peculiar word, civi-logic) he needs to add a price field in the used profile instead?

Comment: Even though you're "not using price sets" - in modern versions of CiviCRM, the event price settings ARE stored in a price set even when you're not using them.  The old interface (to enter prices and labels) is just a UI nicety.  If you click to start using a price set, it will convert the existing price options into a "real" price set.

Comment: How is that a relevant comment? The issue here is that the price option is completely ignored in the front end, whenever the "approval required" option is used. Without any warning or notice, as usual.

Comment: It's relevant because selecting the option to "officially" convert to a price set gives you increased options for displaying the price or not.

Comment: Also, please consider the tone you use when responding?  Everyone here is giving free help.  We're all users of CiviCRM and suffer through the same civi-logic that you do.  Hopefully together we can make things better for each other.